# Is there software to help with group presentation

Tags: group-theory, math-software, group-presentation

I wrote a computer program that generates group presentations.

I would like to know the sizes of the resulting groups. I know that this is [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups).

> Are there good heuristic programs that can try to compute the size of a group given by generators and relations?

I am not interested in apporximating the size. Only in determining the exact size, when the software can do it, hopefully often in my cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Magma Online Calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). For instance, the following code:

```
 F<a, b> := FreeGroup(2);  

 G<x, y>, phi := quo< F | a^2, b^3, (a*b)^4 >;  

 #G
```

Comment: It gives me: "User error: Identifier 'a' has not been declared or assigned"

Comment: @O.L.: Would you like me to edit? I edit and if it is as you wanted keep it. ;)

Comment: @O.L.: I think Daniel did it right. But you may want F<a,b> as $F\langle a,b\rangle$. If so, you can do it via F\langle a,b\rangle between two $.

Comment: @BabakS. No, now it's fine, thanks! I still have some problems with Mathjax. I tried to look at the code of your answer and edit by Daniel Rust, there are no special symbols used, but when I type this myself, it doesn't look the same (line breaks, problems with ><, etc). +1 by the way.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) as well. Regarding to what O.L gave you I am posting an example accordingly:

```
 gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
 gap> a:=f.1;;    b:=f.2;;
 gap> g:=f/[a^2,b^3,(a*b)^4];
 gap> Elements(g);;
 gap> Size(g)
```

If you be familiar to use this software, then you'll wish to use it in sleep even!! It is indeed a wonderful and of course a powerful tool.

Comment: Yay for GAP!! ;-)

Comment: and GAP is included in sage:  http://www.sagemath.org/